# Convert parent object to child in c++ with overloaded operators

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading, parent-child

I have an assignment where we're supposed to overload operators using parent/ child classes and I want to convert a parent object into a child object.  So like boat + plane = seaplane.

An implementation example:

```
seaPlane plane::operator+=(boat rhs)
{
    seaPlane temp;

    temp.displacement = rhs.displacement;
    // etc...
    *this = temp;
    return *this;
}
```

I'm getting two errors here: it says the boat data members are inaccessible and that "no suitable user-defined conversion... exists".

It may also be useful to know that I'm storing the objects in a heterogeneous collection.

Comment: Are you sure you need to overload the += operator and not just the + ? BTW, if there is a common base class to these vehicles then you might be able to use a simpler container for your collection.

Comment: If we overload + but not += the instructor is going to ding us for consistency.  That's kind of the main purpose of this exercise.  Plus, I get the same (first) error in my overload +.  Also, a heterogeneous collection is a requirement as one of the main reasons to use inheritance.

Comment: That seems like a really weird thing for your instructor to require and you've already stumbled upon why. You can't assign to the 'this' pointer because it's a prvalue and can't be assigned to (unless assignment is redefined to do something else). The += operator is meant to accumulate not redefine, so this seems like a bad manipulation of what it's supposed to do. Can you give us any further information about the requirements? You should post them verbatim, so we can help interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, here are things you should try doing. Check the access of your member variables in your boat class. Are they all private or protected? If so, then you can declare inside the node class that the seaPlane class is a friend class. This should give you access.

Something like this.

```
class boat{
friend class plane;
//some code
}
```

Otherwise, you can make the member variables public to allow access. The best option is based on your implementation and what you want.

Lastly, as the comments on your question point out, it is more apt to just overload +.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not sure if we're allowed to use friends so I'll have to check.  Making data members public is sure to take a hit on score so that's off the table.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have the reputation required to comment on Jonathan Smit's answer.

I agree that the access level of the data members of boat is a problem, but since the implementation of += (or + if you follow other advice) is in the class plane, you need to have

```
class boat{
  friend class plane;
  // class definition as before
};
```

Sorry to make this an answer in its own right, I feel it would have better served as a comment.

Comment: Hey, your answer is duly noted. I added that change. Thanks for pointing it out! :)